# IEnumerator script is not working and Coroutine is not running? Unity,C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am writing a script for Enemy in my game, where they will attack hero using Coroutine at a certain interval. Though, while running the game, Enemy is not attacking. I have created two events for enemy animation specific for attack. The IE numerator part of code is not running. Can anyone tell what is going wrong?

I wrote Debug.Log("Hello"), to verify  if it executes but it doesn't print.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float range = 3f;
    [SerializeField] private float timeBetweenAttacks = 1f;

    private Animator anim;
    private GameObject player;
    private bool playerInRange;
    private BoxCollider[] weaponColliders;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        weaponColliders = GetComponentInChildren <BoxCollider[]> ();
        player = GameManager.instance.Player;        
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
        StartCoroutine (attack());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,GameManager.instance.Player.transform.position) < range)
        {
            playerInRange = true;
        }else{
           playerInRange = false;
        }
        
    }

    public IEnumerator attack()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello");
        if(playerInRange && !GameManager.instance.GameOver)
        {
            anim.Play("Attack");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenAttacks);
        }
        yield return null;
        StartCoroutine(attack());        
    }

    public void EnemyBeginAttack(){
        foreach(var weapon in weaponColliders){
            weapon.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    public void EnemyEndAttack(){
        foreach(var weapon in weaponColliders){
            weapon.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if hello never shows. Does start run?

Comment: Yes it does, we tested that portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely the code `weaponColliders = GetComponentInChildren<BoxCollider[]>();`. GetComponentInChildren should only be called with component types (or interface types), but `BoxCollider[]` is an array type.

You should instead use `GetComponentsInChildren<BoxCollider>();`.

Comment: I tried using that but code gave error

Comment: `weaponColliders = GetComponentsInChildren<BoxCollider>();` is definitely the right way to do it. If there's an error it must be coming from your GameManager.instance related code. You should look at the error message, it will tell you the exact line that caused the error.